# Can't output stored information

Tags: c#

I got my program to run but I can't seem to output the stored information that I have.  When I run the program, all the lines are blank. There's more to the code but I figured this is the main code that the program would use to output the information.

```
    class Display
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LandlinePhone yourHomePhone = new LandlinePhone("VTech", "V-4321", "219-999-2345", true);
        Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: {0}", yourHomePhone.Manufacturer);
        Console.WriteLine("Model: {0}", yourHomePhone.Model);
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number: {0}", yourHomePhone.PhoneNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Cordless: {0}", (yourHomePhone.HasCord ? "Yes" : "No"));
}

{
class LandlinePhone : Telephone
{
    private bool hasCord;

    public LandlinePhone()
    {
    }
    public LandlinePhone(string manufacturer, string model, string phoneNumber, bool hasCord)
            : base(manufacturer, model, phoneNumber)
    {
        hasCord = HasCord;
    }

    public bool HasCord
    {
        get
        {
            if (hasCord == true)
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        set
        {
            hasCord = value;
        }
    }

    new public void display()
    {
        base.display();
        Console.WriteLine(HasCord ? "Cordless: Yes" : "Cordless: No");
    }
}


class Telephone
{
    public bool isConnected = true;
    public string lastNumberDialed;
    private string manufacturer;
    private string model;
    private string phoneNumber;



    public Telephone()
    {
    }

    public Telephone(string manufacturer, string model, string phoneNumber)
    {
    }

    public string Manufacturer
    {
        get
        {
            return manufacturer;
        }
        set
        {
            manufacturer = value;
        }
    }

    public string Model
    {
        get
        {
            return model;
        }
        set
        {
            model = value;
        }

    }
    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            phoneNumber = value;
        }
    }
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: {0}", Manufacturer);
        Console.WriteLine("Model: {0}", Model);
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number: {0}", PhoneNumber);
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a tip: your implementation of the `HasCord` property is really odd. A simple `public bool HasCord { get; set; }` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that as well. I'm a noob when it comes to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your **blank constructor** `public Telephone(string manufacturer, string model, string phoneNumber)` in the parent `Telephone` class, you are not setting any property in there, just ignoring the parameters that is why you are not getting any output.

Modify your constructor and set the properties as:

```
public Telephone(string manufacturer, string model, string phoneNumber)
{
   Manufacturer = manufacturer;
   Model = model;
   PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

In your child class `LandlinePhone` you are setting the property `HasCord` and I believe you should get the output `YES` against line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Cordless: {0}", (yourHomePhone.HasCord ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

You may also add `Console.ReadLine()` at the end so that you can see the output during the debug process from visual studio.

Comment: Oh man! Thanks. I've been starring at this for like an hour and couldn't figure it out. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Telephone(string manufacturer, string model, string phoneNumber)
{
//You did not assign the inputs to the properties in your class.
   Manufacturer = manufacturer;
   Model = model;
   phoneNumber;

}
```